# Manipulando pilhas em C

Tags: c, alocação, stack

Sou iniciante em C e tenho o seguinte exercício:

> O Estacionamento EstacioneAqui contém uma única alameda que guarda até
>   dez carros. Existe apenas uma entrada/saída no estacionamento, em uma
>   extremidade da alameda. Se chegar um cliente para retirar um carro que
>   não seja o mais próximo da saída, todos os carros bloqueando seu
>   caminho sairão do estacionamento, o carro do cliente será manobrado
>   para fora do estacionamento, e os outros carros voltarão a ocupar a
>   mesma sequência inicial. Escreva um programa em C que processe um
>   conjunto de entradas. Cada entrada contém um 'E', de entrada, ou um
>   'S', de saída, e o número da placa do carro. Presume-se que os carros
>   cheguem e partam na ordem especificada pela entrada. O programa deve
>   imprimir uma mensagem sempre que um carro chegar ou sair. Quando um
>   carro chegar, a mensagem deve especificar se existe ou não vaga para o
>   carro no estacionamento. Se não houver vaga, o carro partirá sem
>   entrar no estacionamento. Quando um carro sair do estacionamento, a
>   mensagem deverá incluir o número de vezes em que o carro foi manobrado
>   para fora do estacionamento para permitir que outros carros saíssem.

As funções push e pop parecem estar funcionando normalmente, porém quando atribuo a função push a uma outra (manobra por exemplo), não consigo salvar na pilha. Segue códigos:

struct:

```
#define 10
struct veiculo
{
    int placa;
    int manobra;
};
struct pilha
{
    struct veiculo item[tamanho];
    int topo;
};
```

push:

```
void push(struct pilha *pEstacionamento, struct veiculo *carro, int placaDig, int manobraCar)
{
    if(pCheia(pEstacionamento))
    {
        printf("Estacionamento cheio.");
        getch();
    }
    pEstacionamento->topo = pEstacionamento->topo+1;
    pEstacionamento->item[pEstacionamento->topo].placa = placaDig;
    pEstacionamento->item[pEstacionamento->topo].manobra = manobraCar;

}

struct veiculo pop(struct pilha *pEstacionamento)
{
    struct veiculo valor;
    if(pVazia(pEstacionamento))
    {
        printf("Estacionamento vazio");
        getch();
        valor.placa = -1;
        return valor;
    }

    valor = pEstacionamento->item[pEstacionamento->topo];
    pEstacionamento->topo = pEstacionamento->topo - 1;
    return valor;
}
```

manobra:

```
void manobra(struct pilha *pEstacionamento, char status, int placa )
{
    struct pilha pEstacionamentoAux;
    inicializa(&pEstacionamentoAux);
    struct veiculo carro;
    int manobraAux;
    int placaAux;

    if(status == 'e')
    {
        if(pCheia(pEstacionamento))
        {
            printf("Estacionamento cheio.");
            getch();
        }

        manobraAux = 0;
        //pega o valor da placa e manobra como zero e add na pilha
        push(&pEstacionamento, &carro, placa, manobraAux);

    }
    else if(status == 's')
    {
        if(pVazia(pEstacionamento))
        {
            printf("Estacionamento vazio");
            getch();

        }

        while(!pVazia(pEstacionamento))
        {
            carro = pop(&pEstacionamento->topo);
            placaAux = carro.placa;
            manobraAux = carro.manobra;

            if(placaAux == placa)
            {
                printf("Seu carro com a placa: %d , foi retirado do estacionamento com %d manobras.", placaAux, manobraAux);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                manobraAux = manobraAux + 1;
                push(&pEstacionamentoAux, &carro, placaAux, manobraAux);
            }
        }

        while(!pVazia(&pEstacionamentoAux))
        {
            carro = pop(&pEstacionamentoAux);
            placaAux = carro.placa;
            manobraAux = carro.manobra;
            push(&pEstacionamento, &carro, placaAux, manobraAux);
        }
    }
```

Se alguém puder ajudar com alguma dica de como prosseguir, agradeço.

Comment: Descreva melhor seu problema, está muito abstrato.

Comment: Testei a função push normalmente através do main(), só que quando uso a função push dentro de outra função no caso manobra(), e tento recupera os dados, a função me retorna "lixos".

Comment: Vai ser um pouco difícil a gente analisar tudo desta forma. Dê uma lida nisto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Não se isto ajuda, mas `tamanho` parece não estar definido. No início `#define 10` não devia ser `#define tamanho 10` ?

Comment: À primeira vista o erro está na forma como fazes a invocação da função push dentro da função manobra. A função manobra recebe como parâmetro, entre outros, um apontador para uma variável do tipo 'struct pilha'. O que está a acontecer é que estás a passar para a função push, não a variável pEstacionamento, mas sim o endereço desta variável (o endereço do apontador, e não o endereço da variável. Assim, sugiro que substituas a invocação desta função de push(&pEstacionamento, &carro, placa, manobraAux); para push(pEstacionamento, &carro, placa, manobraAux);. Ja agora, o parâmetro carro não é usado

Comment: É o tipo de pergunta ruim para Stack Overflow, basicamente está pedindo para alguém resolver um exercício, a resposta vai ser provavelmente inútil para qualquer um que vá procurar o histórico do SO depois.

Comment: Concordo com o @bruno. Vale registrar como resposta, não?

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma solução (testada) para o exercício proposto, a lógica é basicamente a mesma do seu código:

```
/* ****************************************************************** */
/* *                         estacionamento.c                       * */
/* ****************************************************************** */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ESTACIONAMENTO_MAX_TAM        (10)
#define PLACA_NULL                    (-1)
#define SUCESSO                       (0)
#define ERRO_ESTACIONAMENTO_CHEIO     (-1)
#define ERRO_MANOBRA_INVALIDA         (-2)


typedef enum manobra_e manobra_t;
typedef struct veiculo_s veiculo_t;
typedef struct estacionamento_s estacionamento_t;


enum manobra_e
{
    manobEntrada,
    manobSaida
};


struct veiculo_s
{
    int placa;
};


struct estacionamento_s
{
    veiculo_t vaga[ ESTACIONAMENTO_MAX_TAM ];
    int qtd;
};


void estacionamento_inicializar( estacionamento_t * e )
{
    memset( e, 0, sizeof(estacionamento_t) );
}


int estacionamento_push( estacionamento_t * e, veiculo_t v )
{
    if( e->qtd == ESTACIONAMENTO_MAX_TAM )
        return ERRO_ESTACIONAMENTO_CHEIO;

    e->vaga[ e->qtd++ ] = v;

    return SUCESSO;
}


veiculo_t estacionamento_pop( estacionamento_t * e )
{
    if( e->qtd == 0 )
    {
        veiculo_t v;
        v.placa = PLACA_NULL;
        return v;
    }

    return e->vaga[ --e->qtd ];
}


int estacionamento_manobrar_veiculo( estacionamento_t * e, manobra_t m, int placa )
{
    switch( m )
    {
        case manobEntrada :
        {
            veiculo_t v;
            v.placa = placa;

            if( estacionamento_push( e, v ) == ERRO_ESTACIONAMENTO_CHEIO )
                return ERRO_ESTACIONAMENTO_CHEIO;

            return 1;
        }

        case manobSaida :
        {
            veiculo_t v;
            estacionamento_t aux;
            int qtd_manobras = 0;

            estacionamento_inicializar( &aux );

            while(1)
            {               
                v = estacionamento_pop( e );

                if( v.placa == PLACA_NULL )
                    break;

                qtd_manobras++;

                if( v.placa == placa )
                    break;

                estacionamento_push( &aux, v );
            }

            while(1)
            {               
                v = estacionamento_pop( &aux );

                if( v.placa == PLACA_NULL )
                    break;

                estacionamento_push( e, v );
            }

            return qtd_manobras;
        }

        default :
        {
            return ERRO_MANOBRA_INVALIDA;
        }
    }
}

void estacionamento_listar_veiculos( estacionamento_t * e )
{
    int i = 0;

    if( !e->qtd )
    {
        printf("Estacionamento Vazio!\n");
        return;
    }

    printf( "Estacionamento:\n" );

    for( i = 0; i < e->qtd; i++ )
        printf( "   Vaga %d / Placa: %d\n", i, e->vaga[i].placa );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int qtd = 0;
    estacionamento_t e;

    estacionamento_inicializar( &e );

    estacionamento_listar_veiculos( &e );

    estacionamento_manobrar_veiculo( &e, manobEntrada, 1010 );
    estacionamento_manobrar_veiculo( &e, manobEntrada, 2020 );
    estacionamento_manobrar_veiculo( &e, manobEntrada, 3030 );
    estacionamento_manobrar_veiculo( &e, manobEntrada, 4040 );
    estacionamento_manobrar_veiculo( &e, manobEntrada, 5050 );

    estacionamento_listar_veiculos( &e );

    qtd = estacionamento_manobrar_veiculo( &e, manobSaida, 3030 );

    printf( "Retirei veiculo do estacionamento com %d manobras!\n", qtd );

    estacionamento_listar_veiculos( &e );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Espero ter ajudado!